# PWA and magento

Tags: magento2, pwa

I've readed that Adobe added the PWA to Magento.

But on my phone it doesn't create any PWA. Does it do this natively or do we need extensions ?

Comment: Think of a pwa as a site. Your phone doesn't create a site but loads it based on someone else's code. Same with a pwa.

Answer (score 2):

The PWA studio is a set of tools you can use to build a PWA, unless you do that you will not have a PWA at all. See https://magento-research.github.io/pwa-studio/ for how to set up a PWA.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install PWA Studio in Magento root installation. After that it will be available through URL.